# How to noauto fstab mounting of remote

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, cifs

I manage to mount a distant remote using :

```
sudo mount -t cifs //adress /mnt/point/ -o credentials=/home/me/.credentials
```

I tried to integrate this into my fstab using:

```
//adress /mnt/point/ cifs noauto,credentials=/home/me/.credentials     0      0
```

Note that the `noauto` option is needed as I want to mount manually by clicking on the GUI.

However, nothing shows up when I reboot on my GUI:

[image]

See the empty `other locations`.

Comment: Check, after adding the line to fstab, whether you can mount the drive with the command `sudo mount //adress` or `sudo mount /mnt/point/`. That will show you did it right. Obviously, something you mount as root cannot be mounted through the Gui, so do not expect that to work with your current setup.

Comment: This works. I also aded the `users` option so I can mount it without being root. It still does not show up in the GUI though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work in the graphical user interface, you will need to allow users to perform the mount. This can be implemented by adding the `user` or the `users` option.

For having the volume appear in the file manager, there are two options:

- Mount the volume under `/media` instead. Mounts under `/media` automatically are shown as an icon in the file manager for all users. That also applied for mounts under a user's /home directory, but then only for that user .
- Alternatively, add the mount option `x-gvfs-show` to the line for the volume in `/etc/fstab`.